# Fontspec and Adforn

Tags: fontspec, debugging

I keep getting a strange error when I load adforn with my documents. It boils down to fontspec changing the encoding from U to TU, and then it throws me an error and automatically updated the encoding with defaults.

I have solved this by making a new file in my texmf called TUOrnementsADF.fd containing the same content as the Uornements one. I was wondering if there's a better way to solve this. (Or if this would have the maintainer fix the problem).

This only really bothers me because I use vim-latexsuite, and that automatically registers this as an error and takes me to the file the error comes from. Just an aside.

An MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

Hi\adfast{1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Load `adforn` after `fontspec`.

Comment: I didn't think about that. It usually gets loaded automatically for me by polyglossia.

Comment: `polyglossia` also loads `fontspec`; in this case load `adforn` after `polyglossia`.

Comment: I think the best approach would really be to use the OTF fonts provided by the font designer, rather than the type1 versions supported via the traditional font mechanism. The package isn't really intended for use with `fontspec`, frankly. It is rather a hack to allow the fonts to be accessed using traditional engines. If you aren't restricted to fonts accessible in that way, because you aren't using such an engine, there's no reason to use `adforn`. @egreg

Comment: @cfr There's a convenience to the package in that the symbols have commands set up for them already. Unless that's available without your package?

Comment: @cfr The missing braces are a bug notwithstanding.

Comment: @cfr The bug appeared again and not in connection with `fontspec`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462849/4427 I think it should be fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is a small bug in `adforn.sty`, which does, at the beginning,

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{adforn}[2010/07/25 v1.0 adforn CFR]
\RequirePackage{pifont}
\Pifont{OrnementsADF}
```

but the last call should be braced. The effect is that `OrnementsADF` becomes the current font and `fontspec` tries to load it with the TU encoding, failing at the task. Calls of `\adforn` or `\adfast` in the document are not affected.

Workaround: load `adforn` after `fontspec` (or other packages that depend on it, such as `polyglossia`), but the quirk should be fixed like

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{adforn}[2010/07/25 v1.0 adforn CFR]
\RequirePackage{pifont}
{\Pifont{OrnementsADF}}
```

so the change in the current font, which is only necessary to load the `.fd` file, is not carried along at group end.

The same strategy is adopted at the end of `pifont.sty`:

```
[...]
\newcommand{\ding}{\Pisymbol{pzd}}
\def\dingfill#1{\Pifill{pzd}{#1}}
\def\dingline#1{\Piline{pzd}{#1}}
\newenvironment{dinglist}[1]{\begin{Pilist}{pzd}{#1}}%
  {\end{Pilist}}
\newenvironment{dingautolist}[1]{\begin{Piautolist}{pzd}{#1}}%
  {\end{Piautolist}}
{\Pifont{pzd}}
{\Pifont{psy}}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `pifont.sty'.
```