# Conflict between tufte-book, adforn, and pdfx

Tags: tufte, pdfx

When I try to use the tufte-book class with the adforn and pdfx packages, I am getting a problem with symbol substitutions.  For example:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{adforn} 
\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
\textcopyright
\end{document}
```

Generates:

[image: Failure]

If I do any one of (a) use the article class instead (b) leave out adforn (c) leave out pdfx, I get the proper symbol:

[image: Success]

I haven't a clue how to start diagnosing this. I could probably work around by creating my own copyright symbol, but I worry that other symbols in my large document might also be wrong. Any suggestions? Can others duplicate this?

I am using pdflatex with MiKtex on Windows.

Edit: this compiles for me without errors. Here is my [logfile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r9XXaKz-SexZo_LTenBrPTApxebNE05x), I didn't see anything relevant.

Comment: Do you need the call of `pdfx`? Without it the compiles without error messages. With `pdfx` I gert error messages. Do you get some? Add them to your question please. BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I don't get any errors, no. I can try to attach my log file though. I didn't see any relevant warnings. Thanks for the welcome, I have gotten much use previous answers on the site!

Comment: The printer I am preparing this for requires pdf/X compliance. If there is a better way to achieve that I would be happy to hear.

Comment: Well, you are using an older version `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.5.9)`, the current version is `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6880 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.12.1)`. to get the code compiled i have to change the order of `pdfx` and `adforn` and still receives an error message `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is common with `tufte` classes: they load `hyperref` too early. With `pdfx`, it is this package that should load it.

There is another small problem about `tufte-book` loading `xcolor` with options and `pdfx` doing the same with different options.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{cmyk,hyperref}{xcolor}
\documentclass[nohyper]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}

\begin{document}

\textcopyright

\end{document}
```

If you want to use the same `hyperref` setup as `tufte-book`, add

```
\hypersetup{
  pdfborder = {0 0 0},
  bookmarksdepth = section,
  citecolor = DarkGreen,
  linkcolor = DarkBlue,
  urlcolor = DarkGreen,
}
```

before `\begin{document}`.

Why does the issue show when `adforn` is loaded? It's a bug of `adforn` explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394388/4427. It causes the `U` fontencoding to be current when `pdfx` is loaded, so for reasons too long to be explained, L8U ends up being assigned as the default encoding for `\textcopyright` and *many* other commands, which is wrong because this encoding is only for internal use.

The fix I add below might be sufficient, but it's best to use `nohyper` anyways.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{cmyk,hyperref}{xcolor}
\documentclass[nohyper]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{adforn}
\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont % work around the adforn bug

\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}

\hypersetup{
  pdfborder = {0 0 0},
  bookmarksdepth = section,
  citecolor = DarkGreen,
  linkcolor = DarkBlue,
  urlcolor = DarkGreen,
}

\begin{document}

\textcopyright

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or maybe not. I don't know how I generated it.

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to work! Though now there are other problems from pdfx, but perhaps I can sort them out.

Comment: When I  try to compile the example in the question, I get an error, which is fine, and then it hangs on loading the MPS to PDF converter.

Comment: Sounds like I should be thankful this thing compiles for me at all!

Comment: For future reference: the nohyper option seemed to cause a lot of trouble (on my real doc, not the test), but just including your adforn fix resolved the character problem